# How to find unique value from an array in sorted order using for loop and sort() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, for-loop

My array is:

const arr = [1, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 5, 9, 7, 5, 44, 6]

Comment: why not use a single iteration without sorting? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this , find unique values from an array in sorted order?
const arr = [1, 5, 7, 44, 5, 9, 4, 5, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8];

const arr = [1, 5, 7, 44, 5, 9, 4, 5, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8];
const sortedArr = arr.sort();
console.log(sortedArr);

for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    const element = sortedArr[i];
    
}

Comment: Question is extremely unclear

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could go about sorting your array:

```
const arr = [1, 5, 7, 44, 5, 9, 4, 5, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8];

const uniqueArr = arr.filter(function(item, idx, self) {
    return self.indexOf(item) == idx;
})

const sortedArr = uniqueArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
console.log(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 4, 8, 10, 5, 7, 5, 9, 7, 5, 44, 6];
      arr.sort((a,b) => {return a - b;});
let len = arr.length;
const unique = [];

for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
  if(unique.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1){
     unique.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(unique);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.